# FFT 1d transform

Tags: cufft

I want to use cufft to perform a FFT , I create an array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], and I use

```
    cufftPlan1d(&plan 8, CUFFT_C2C,1)
```

to create a plan and then I use

```
    cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, CUFFT_FORWARD)
```

to perform FFT. I have transform the array to a complex array with the image part is 0 before using it. I got a result like that:

```
first : 1.000000 0.000000  after 4.500000 0.000000 
first : 2.000000 0.000000  after -0.500000 1.207107 
first : 3.000000 0.000000  after -0.500000 0.500000 
first : 4.000000 0.000000  after -0.500000 0.207107 
first : 5.000000 0.000000  after -0.500000 0.000000 
first : 6.000000 0.000000  after -0.500000 -0.207107 
first : 7.000000 0.000000  after -0.500000 -0.500000 
first : 8.000000 0.000000  after -0.500000 -1.207107
```

first is original data element, after is the result cufftExecC2C compute. I want to know if this result is right. I think the first output result element is 36=1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 while it is 4.5. So where is wrong?

Comment: (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8) / 8 = 4.5 so it's correct based on Fourier transform formula

Comment: my bad, I print the result with every element dividing 8. So 4.5 is right.,at that time I ignored it.